# Tmux log output

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, tmux

Im looking for a solution to an issue regarding tmux. One of my scripts ns2server stopped working recently when running start (using tmux) but not in debug mode (not using tmux).

I found that using tee to get the output of tmux was for some reason stopping Natural Selection 2 server from running.

```
tmux new-session -d -s ${servicename} "${executable} ${parms}|tee -a '${consolelog}'"
```

I removed tee and the server started working again.

```
tmux new-session -d -s ${servicename} "${executable} ${parms}"
```

There have also been reports that other server scripts do not update the consolelog unless you enter the tmux session and press return.

Im guessing there is a better way to send the output of tmux to a file than using tee. Does anyone have any suggestions on this? Thank you

Project homepage

http://danielgibbs.co.uk/scripts/

https://github.com/dgibbs64/linuxgameservers

EDIT: I have looked at this answer [Is there an equivalent of GNU Screen's "log" command in tmux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5832/is-there-an-equivalent-of-gnu-screens-log-command-in-tmux). Although very useful does not quite answer my question. The answer to the other question talks about toggling logging on and off. I require logging to be on by default as soon as a new session is started. Plus I would rather not have to create a .tmux.conf file if this can be avoided. Maybe there is a way for me to script the toggling on by default when the session is started.

EDIT: Found a good solution

```
tmux new-session -d -s ${servicename} "${executable} ${parms}"
tmux pipe-pane -o -t ${servicename} "exec cat >> '${consolelog}'"
```

the second line activates logging in the session and sends it to a file.

Comment: I think it is a good question - but I think the other is better, and you should find all you need in the answers there as well. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5832/is-there-an-equivalent-of-gnu-screens-log-command-in-tmux

Comment: I have looked at this answer. Although very useful does not quite answer my question. The answer to the other question talks about toggling logging on and off. I require logging to be on by default as soon as a new session is started. Plus I would rather not have to create a .tmux.conf file if this can be avoided. Maybe there is a way for me to script the toggling on by default when the session is started.

Comment: I think I may of found the solution. 

    tmux pipe-pane -o -t ns2-server "exec cat >>/home/ns2server/test.txt"

Comment: @dgibbs I voted it to reopen this question, but you have to do something for it:

Please add the requirements, that you have stated here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148420/tmux-log-output#comment-241032 and that differentiates your question from the suggested duplicate here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5832/is-there-an-equivalent-of-gnu-screens-log-command-in-tmux.

Then add your solution as an answer to this question and accept it, if it really solved your problem.

Comment: Yes I would like the question reopened as the other question did not specifically answer my question. I did manage to figure out that using pipe-pane option may be the solution but had to figure out the switches myself. I believe reopening the question will benefit others. Hopefully this gets seen and I can correctly add the answer to the question